musixlyr force text exception in Musixtex
It is needed to force text in musixlyr when there is no note in pivot voice. The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[%
border={1pt -2pt 2pt -1pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Acordes}{\B K\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{6 4}} \B V \B I \B K\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{6 4}} \B I \B K\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{6 4}} \B V \B I}%
\setsongraise{1}{-0.1cm}
\parindent0mm
\sepbarrules
%\generalsignature{1}
%\generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}2}
\instrumentnumber{1}
%\setinterinstrument{1}{12pt}%espacio entre Voz y Piano
\interstaff{12}%espacio entre pentagramas del piano
%\staffbotmarg7\Interligne% set verticle space in one staff score
\setclef16
\setstaffs12
\nobarnumbers
%\smallmusicsize
\startpiece
\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{1}{Acordes}
\notes{\color{black}\zwh{G}\hu{e}}|\zwh{g}\hu{j}\en%
\notes\hu{d}|\hu{i}\en\bar%
\notes{\color{black}\zwh{J}\wh{e}}|\zwh{g}\wh{j}\en\setdoubleBAR\bar%
\notes{\color{black}\zwh{G}\hu{N}}|\zwh{e}\hu{j}\en%
\notes\hsk|\zhl{d}\hu{i}\en\bar%
\notes\zwh{J}\wh{N}|\zwh{e}\wh{j}\en\setdoubleBAR\bar%
\notes{\color{black}\zwh{G}\hu{c}}|\zwh{g}\hu{l}\en%
\notes\hu{b}|\hu{k}\en\bar%
\notes\zwh{J}\wh{c}|\zwh{g}\wh{l}\en\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}

The current output is as follow:

The desired output is:


The solution is as follow (just use the command \lyr):
\documentclass[%
border={1pt -2pt 2pt -1pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Acordes}{\B K\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{6 4}} \B V \B I \B K\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{6 4}} \B V \B I \B K\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{6 4}} \B V \B I}%
\setsongraise{1}{-0.1cm}
\parindent0mm
\sepbarrules
%\generalsignature{1}
%\generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}2}
\instrumentnumber{1}
%\setinterinstrument{1}{12pt}%espacio entre Voz y Piano
\interstaff{12}%espacio entre pentagramas del piano
%\staffbotmarg7\Interligne% set verticle space in one staff score
\setclef16
\setstaffs12
\nobarnumbers
%\smallmusicsize
\startpiece
\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{1}{Acordes}
\notes{\color{black}\zwh{G}\hu{e}}|\zwh{g}\hu{j}\en%
\notes\hu{d}|\hu{i}\en\bar%
\notes{\color{black}\zwh{J}\wh{e}}|\zwh{g}\wh{j}\en\setdoubleBAR\bar%
\notes{\color{black}\zwh{G}\wh{N}}|\zhl{e}\hu{j}\en%
\notes\lyr\hsk|\zhl{d}\hu{i}\en\bar%
\notes\zwh{J}\wh{N}|\zwh{e}\wh{j}\en\setdoubleBAR\bar%
\notes{\color{black}\zwh{G}\hu{c}}|\zwh{g}\hu{l}\en%
\notes\hu{b}|\hu{k}\en\bar%
\notes\zwh{J}\wh{c}|\zwh{g}\wh{l}\en\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}

The output is as follow:

